# check if .one() is empty sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am running a query based off of other ids for the query. The problem i have is that sometimes the query won't find a result. Instead of having the entire program crash, how can I check to see if the result will be None?

This is the query I have:

```
sub_report_id = DBSession.query(TSubReport.ixSubReport).filter(and_(TSubReport.ixSection==sectionID[0], TSubReport.ixReport== reportID[0])).one()
```

When the code gets executed and no results are found, I get a NoResultFound exception

```
NoResultFound: No row was found for one()
```

is there a way to just skip the query if there is not going to be a result?

***Found the solution on SO***(couldn't find it before)
[Getting first row from sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110033/getting-first-row-from-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use `first()` function instead of `one()`. It will return None if there is no results.

```
sub_report_id = DBSession.query(TSubReport.ixSubReport).filter(
    and_(
        TSubReport.ixSection==sectionID[0], 
        TSubReport.ixReport== reportID[0])).first()
```

see documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.first)

Comment: I ended up using a try catch but this seems more clean

Comment: @john Yes its cleaner. The API throws a exception to warn you that something went wrong. Basically `.one()` should only be used getting only one result is mandatory for the rest of the method. (good example is when you retreive an element by id and want to perform an operation on it. In this case you know the execution should stop if the element does not exists.) Remember exception thrown by API are suposed to help you, they should get in your way.

Comment: Note that there's a subtle difference between `.one()` and `.first()` - if there are _more than one result_, `.one()` will also fail, while `.first()` will just return the first result and omit the rest. May lead to strange behaviour when you accidentally get two sub-reports in the same section

Comment: that's what I was thinking but I funny enough I ended up changing a few other things which let me avoid this situtation

Comment: And just to be blatantly clear, `None` returns `false`

Answer (score 58):

You can also use `one_or_none()`, this returns `None` when there's no result found and is syntactically clearer than `first()`. No error handling required.

ref: [one_or_none()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one_or_none)

Comment: That is not semantically equivalent to `first()`. `first()` silently discards all but the first row; `one_or_none()` raises an exception on multiple results. If you're looking to replace `one()`, `one_or_none()` is definitely the better answer.

Answer (score 18):

How would SQLAlchemy know there wasn't going to be a result without doing the query?

You should catch the exception and handle it then:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import NoResultFound

try:
    sub_report_id = DBSession.query(TSubReport.ixSubReport).filter(and_(TSubReport.ixSection==sectionID[0], TSubReport.ixReport== reportID[0])).one()
except NoResultFound:
    sub_report_id = []  # or however you need to handle it
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, not wanting to use .first() for my use case, but this answer didn't help me, as I needed to first import the error namespace in order to catch it.  As in: from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import NoResultFound

Comment: This is good approach as it also substitutes any further "if sub_report_id is None: ..." logical clauses.