# What's the equivalent of peewee's DoesNotExist in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, peewee

I've been using peewee with SQLite for some time and now I'm switching to SQLAlchemy with Postgres and I can't find equivalent of DoesNotExist (see example)

```
try:
    return models.User.get(models.User.id == userid)
except models.DoesNotExist:
    return None
```

Do you know how to achieve the same with SQLAlchemy? I've checked stuff which I can import from sqlalchemy.ext but nothing seemed right.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110033/getting-first-row-from-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest could be this one: - http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound

**Code Sample:**

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import NoResultFound

try:
    user = session.query(User).one()
except NoResultFound, e:
    print "No users found"
```

Comment: or you can replace the whole `try` clause with the equivalent `session.query(User).one_or_none()`

Comment: Now it's updated checkout this link instead - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.NoResultFound

Answer (score -3):

Peewee *does* work with Postgresql, you know. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to use something more advanced than peewee

Comment: Peewees a hell of a lot better than django and people have built advanced things with django's orm.